# Redirection not work from non www to www(https) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!

Tags: joomla-2.5, .htaccess-configuration, ssl, https

I'm currently have a website which runs under https and work with no issue and I've tried to do something on my .htaccess file so that when I try http://abc.com it will redirect to https://www.abc.com
However, I've tried a few items below and my redirection does not work:
- .htaccess has been enabled with AllowOverride and tested readable.
- filename no issue.
- location of rules has been moved to the beginning of the files but not work
- Syntax tested with the tool available online and debug with no issue.
Below are my .htaccess file for reference:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your 
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the 
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If 
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to 
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed 
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

BTW, I also try to amend it with below, purposely amend to wrong link but there a was no error appear as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://www.abc.coms/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I also went and check my apache logs and found there's an error which involving ssl warn.

> [ssl:warn] [pid 204:tid 412] AH01916: Init: (localhost:443) You
>   configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!

I'm not sure if this will affect my redirection or not but my website currently able to run under https with no issue. 
Please help! TIA!

Comment: Check your server config, the warning means your SSL is probably not set up correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605857/you-configured-https443-on-the-standard-http80-port

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps delete this bit

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And place the following instead

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please also explain exactly what you have changed and why you feel it is advisable -- with the intention to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Hi jamesgerrett, redirection still not work even after changed to the one you suggested. :((